# QuickBooks Online Name Error from def Authenticate section of controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, quickbooks-online

I'm learning rails and integration of app to QB Online. I'm following the minimal video and using cloud 9.  I think I have done everything correctly but I get a name error: in Vendors Controller#authenticate

> undefined local variable or method `quickbooks_oauth_callback_url' for #
>   Highlights the callback = of this:

```
def authenticate
    callback = quickbooks_oauth_callback_url
    token = $qb_oauth_consumer.get_request_token(:oauth_callback => callback)
    Marshal.load(session[:qb_request_token]).get_access_token(:oauth_verifier => params[:oauth_verifier])
    session[:qb_request_token] = token
    session[:qb_request_token] = Marshal.dump(token)
    redirect_to("https://appcenter.intuit.com/Connect/Begin?oauth_token=#{token.token}") and return
  end

def oauth_callback
    at = session[:qb_request_token].get_access_token(:oauth_verifier => params[:oauth_verifier])
    token = at.token
    secret = at.secret
    realm_id = params['realmId']
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Your QuickBooks account has been successfully linked."
end
```

I'm wondering if anyone can see what I did wrong. I get the QB online connect button, but it just errors out when I click it.

Comment: I am getting closer I think, has something to do with Marshal.dump and Marshal.load.  I am now getting the app page at intuit, but then after I authorize errors.

Comment: def oauth_callback
Marshal.load(session[:qb_request_token]).get_access_token(:oauth_verifier => params[:oauth_verifier])
session[:token] = at.token -HERE IS WHERE ERROR HIGHLIGHT IS NOW...
secret = load.secret
realm_id = params['realmId']
redirect_to root_url, notice: "Your QuickBooks account has been successfully linked."